# joining multiple s3 files in scala Programming in AWS Glue

Tags: scala, aws-glue

How to join multiple s3 files in scala? based on the join data I need to insert or update the data into MySQL database.

let me know if there is any kind sample script for this.

Answer (score 0):

Ramesh, though I donot have a scala script to join files and import to Mysql, may be this aws link may give you an idea for creating different dataframes for 3 files from S3 and then join them as needed, before processing for creating/importing to a mysql/redshift tables.

1. Create a Glue crawler & point to the 3 files, generate the database/table catalogs for the S3 files (Ref:[Setting up glue catalog/crawlers](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/build-a-data-lake-foundation-with-aws-glue-and-amazon-s3/) )
2. In your scala scripts, create dataframes for the 3 tables, and then join them as needed.

URL: [Aws examples for Join&Relationalize using Scala.](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-glue-samples/blob/master/examples/JoinAndRelationalize.scala)

Thanks

Yuva

Comment: Please upvote/accept the answer if the provided solution/ link are useful.